# Map APRS data on Windows laptop using Kenwood D710's internal TNC

Tags: aprs, map, windows, kenwood-d710g

My D710G has APRS built in. How can I get that data displayed on a laptop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this I use an RT Systems USB-K5G cable connected to the `COM` port on the back of the control head. On my laptop I'm running Pinpoint APRS v2.0.

### Pinpoint APRS configuration

[image: Pinpoint APRS - Options - APRS tab]
[image: Pinpoint APRS - Options - TNC tab]
[image: Pinpoint APRS - Options - GPS tab]

### Kenwood D710G settings

- `601` INTERNAL TNC:

  - DATA BAND: B-BAND
  - DATA SPEED: 1200 bps
  - DCD SENSE: D or RxD BAND
  - TX DELAY: 200 ms
- `602` GPS PORT:

  - BAUD RATE: 9600 bps
  - OUTPUT: WAYPOINT
- `603` WAYPOINT:

  - FORMAT: KENWOOD
  - NAME: 9-CHAR
  - OUTPUT: ALL
- `604` COM PORT:

  - OUTPUT: ON